# Display Two row data in one table TD

Tags: php, mysql

Hello Please help me for the  following problem

Mysql  DATA table is

```
Sno Name    Subject Marks 
1   Test1   Sub1    20
2   Test1   Sub2    20
3   Test1   Sub3    20
4   Test1   Sub4    20
5   Test1   Sub5    20
6   Test2   Sub1    30
7   Test2   Sub2    30
8   Test2   Sub3    30
9   Test2   Sub4    30
10  Test2   Sub5    30
11  Test3   Sub1    40
12  Test3   Sub2    40
13  Test3   Sub3    40
14  Test3   Sub4    40
15  Test3   Sub5    40
```

i want to display like this

```
Sno Name    Marks
1   Test1   100
    Sub1    20
    Sub2    20
    Sub3    20
    Sub4    20
    Sub5    20
2   Test2   150
    Sub1    30
    Sub2    30
    Sub3    30
    Sub4    30
    Sub5    30
3   Test3   200
    Sub1    40
    Sub2    40
    Sub3    40
    Sub4    40
    Sub5    40
```

is it possaible in MYSQL PHP.

Comment: Short answer, impossible to be exactly the same as your output

Comment: it is very much possible

Comment: This makes no sence at all. Why do you save 5x Test1 with SNO 1-5 but want to display Test2 with SNO2 ? Your structure dont make any sence...

Comment: can you please explain??

Comment: i use DISTINCT query an i display                                                             Sno Name Marks
1 Test1 100
2 Test2 150
3 Test3 200                                                                                                  IN same table i need to add those details

Answer (score 1):

Two ways of doing this

1) Find all unique names and sum of marks

```
Select Name  AS Heading, SUM(Marks) AS Total FROM table GROUP BY Name
```

and then iterate through the results and query for all records matching the name

```
Select * from table WHERE Name = $result['Heading']
```

2) Get all records, then iterate through the results to group them

```
Select * from table WHERE

$headings = [];
$children = [];
foreach($allrecords as $result)
{
    if (!in_array($result['Name'], $headings)
    {
         $headings[$result['Name']]['Name'] = $result['Name'];
    }
    if (isset($headings[$result['Name']]['Marks']))
    {
        $headings[$result['Name']]['Marks'] += $result['Marks']
    }
    else
    {
        $headings[$result['Name']]['Marks'] = $result['Marks'] 
    }
    $children[$result['Name']][] = $result;
}
```